# How can I get file information in a listbox of files?

Tags: c#, winforms

today's dilemma is that I cannot for the life of me figure out an easy way to write the data (size, date) of a file in a listbox. I have managed to create a listbox that updates whenever changes are made using a FileSystemWatcher, a great recommendation from another user. Now I need to know what the size of these files are and when they where created/modified.

Thank you in advance.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string serviceName = "Spooler";
        public static string directoryLocation = "C:/Windows/System32/spool/PRINTERS/";
        public static int timeoutMilliseconds;
        FileSystemWatcher watcher;

        public Form1()
        {
            //listBox1.

            InitializeComponent();
            RefreshQueue();
            watch();
        }

        private void watch()
        {
            watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = directoryLocation;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite & NotifyFilters.LastAccess & NotifyFilters.FileName & NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnChanged;
            watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            watcher.Renamed += OnChanged;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshQueue();
        }
```

---

```
     public void PrintQueue()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryLocation);
        foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTime))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(directoryLocation + fi);
        }
    }

    public void RefreshQueue()
    {
        PrintQueue();
        label1.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What about: `listBox1.Items.Add($"{fi.FullName}:{fi.Length});`

Comment: Better switch to a ListView with columns for the various things. Or descend a class from FileInfo with a new ToString method which can then add to the ListBox.

Comment: Thanks TaW, I did have my suspicions that I might have to do that.

Comment: Jeroen's answer is good too, if you don't want to switch to a listView, but keep in mind that with listboxes, the information will not be aligned.